# The Kendall tau distance

Tags: statistics

In book "Algorithms, 4th Edition by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne" is written

> The
>   Kendall tau distance between two rankings is
>   the number of pairs that are in different order
>   in the two rankings. For example, the Kendall
>   tau distance between 0 3 1 6 2 5 4 and
>   1 0 3 6 4 2 5 is four because the pairs 0-1,
>   3-1, 2-4, 5-4 are in different relative order in
>   the two rankings, but all other pairs are in the same relative order.

But what about 6-0, 6-3 and etc, these pairs are in different relative order too. I don't understand this explanation. May anybody explain it well, please?

Comment: Maybe this question will be closed as duplicate, but I couldn't have found an explanation in others questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both of the sequences, 0 is before 6. Thus (6,0) does not increase the Kendall tau distance. Similarly, 3 is always before 6 in the sequences.

Regarding 0-1, 0 is before 1 in the first sequence while 1 is before 0 in the second one. That's why (0,1) is increasing the Kendall tau distance.